# disable textarea resize handlers jQuery css

Tags: jquery, html, css

How do I disable textarea resizing handler in jQuery?

```
function textArea(){
    $("#textarea").css("resize",none); // not working
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('textarea').click(function () {
    $(this).css('resize', 'none');
});
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AX39R/)**

You were missing `"` after `$("#textarea`

And you need to wrap `none` around `"` or `'`